# How can we catch the acces denied exception?

Tags: 8

I've run into a case where users need to be redirected to the login page when they try to access a page without having the permission to access it.

How can I catch an exception  of the `AccessDeniedHttpException` class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To catch the access error you can use a symfony event listener:

> If your listener calls setResponse() on the
>   GetResponseForExceptionEvent, event, propagation will be stopped and
>   the response will be sent to the client.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#working-with-the-kernel-exception-event

This is an example how to return a `GetResponseForExceptionEvent` event:

**Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\CustomPageExceptionHtmlSubscriber**

```
public function on403(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event) {
    $custom_403_path = $this->configFactory->get('system.site')->get('page.403');
    if (!empty($custom_403_path)) {
      $this->makeSubrequestToCustomPath($event, $custom_403_path, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }
  }
```

For your own Event Subscriber extend `DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber`.

```
class MyCustomPageExceptionHtmlSubscriber extends DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber
```

See the complete example:

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/CustomPageExceptionHtmlSubscriber.php

which extends

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber.php

You would have to use a higher priority, so that your code will run first.

---

In most cases it might be easier to configure a url pointing to a custom controller here:

```
/admin/config/system/site-information
```

BTW the example code above is how core implements this configuration.

Comment: I've been fighting with infinite loops while trying to setup an event_subscriber `setResponse()` on `KernelEvents::VIEW` , in a situation where an exception was thrown, until I found your answer ! Very useful, thanks a lot. I noticed you posted an answer on about every single post about event listeners ;-)