# How to suppress default HtmlException?

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I need to turn off 404 & related Exceptions. Need to handle it in custom way.

I've implemented an `EventSubscriber` with listener for `kernel.exception` event.

But `$event->setException()` cannot receive NULL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct approach. Don't do all the work yourself, extend  `DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber` for 403/404 or `HttpExceptionSubscriberBase` for general exceptions.

As example see this question for access denied: [How can we catch the acces denied exception in drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211195/how-can-we-catch-the-acces-denied-exception-in-drupal-8)

The most important thing is to use a higher priority than the core event you want to override.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I'm altering Response object on kernel.response event