# Dynamically change the "access denied page" title and body

Tags: routes

This is not a question about changing or preprocessing the twig template of the 403 page.

I have a controller with an `access` function called by the `_custom_access` key of my route.

In some circumstance, this function is returning `AccessResult::forbidden("a good reason");` which lead to my default `403` page.

Most of the case, this is the behavior I would like to have, but in few cases, I would like to have another title and another message for this page like "You can not access because you eat too much chocolate"

Should I create a new custom error route and send a new response to this route from my `access` function? (hint: I tried without success)

Any idea?

**Edit to add:** Thanks to 4k4, I have added a custom `ExceptionHtmlSubscriber` extending `DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber` in order to override the `on403()` method.

Here is my code:

```
class TXSExceptionHtmlSubscriber extends DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function on403(ExceptionEvent $event) {
    $my_condition=extract_from_event($event);
    if($my_condition){
      // I am not sure it is what should be done here
      $this->makeSubrequest($event, '/my_custom_error_path/my_custom_error_code', Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }else {
      parent::$this->on403($event);
    }
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected static function getPriority() {
    return 1000;
  }
}
```

So far, I have 2 questions:

1-Unfortunately my custom `on403()` method is never called (on the other hand, the `on403()` method `DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber` is called): What I am missing?

2-Let say that my custom `on403()` method is called: what should be the code to redirect the user on my custom `403` page containing my custom message (ie: it could be nice to display the reason of the AccessResult `AccessResult::forbidden("a good reason");`

Comment: `but in few cases` – What cases exactly? What conditions?

Comment: For example role_A doesn't have access but needs a custom 403 message but role_B who haven't access too will be ok with the default 403 page.

Answer (score 1):

Access functions are only for calculating access results. You can't do anything else because this function is called multiple times, not only for incoming routes but also for outbound links.

To set a response use `on403()` of an ExceptionHtmlSubscriber. You can also set the result of a sub-request if you want a themed 403 message. See [How can we catch the acces denied exception?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211195/how-can-we-catch-the-acces-denied-exception)

**Edit: Answering further questions**

> 1-Unfortunately my custom on403() method is never called (on the other
> hand, the on403() method DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber is called):
> What I am missing?

You need to register the service in *mymodule.services.yml*:

```
services:
  mymodule.exception_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\MymoduleExceptionHtmlSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

> 2-Let say that my custom on403() method is called: what should be the
> code to redirect the user on my custom 403 page containing my custom
> message (ie: it could be nice to display the reason of the
> AccessResult AccessResult::forbidden("a good reason");

You find the message in the exception object:

```
public function on403(ExceptionEvent $event) {
  // ...
  if ($my_condition) {
    $message = $event->getThrowable()->getMessage();
    $event->setResponse(new Response($message, 403));
  }
}
```

BTW you don't need to call `parent::on403($event)` because the parent registered with a lower priority will be called automatically when your event subscriber doesn't set a response.

Comment: Thank you. it looks like it is the solution, but I am stuck with 2 issues. Would you mind to read my updated question?

Answer (score 0):

If your eventsubscriber is not working yet, try updating the services yml file and adding the constructor to the class.

```
services:
  mymodule.exception_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\MymoduleExceptionHtmlSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@http_kernel', '@logger.channel.php', '@redirect.destination', '@router.no_access_checks', '@access_manager']
```