# How to write custom access for a route which redirects the user to another route if a condition is true

Tags: 8, routes

If I visit **example.route.one** and certain conditions are fulfilled I want to redirect it to **example.route.two** OR else access should be allowed.
How Can I achieve this? I tried writing the redirection in the custom controller **routeOne** but this method does not work properly for non-admin users, the issue being if I click/visit **example.route** it automatically redirects me to **example.route.two**

Menu Yml file - example.links.menu.yml

```
example.route:
  title: 'Route Example'
  route_name: example.route
  parent: system.admin
  description: 'Contains Route Example'
  weight: -99

example.route.one:
  title: 'Route One'
  route_name: example.route.one
  description: 'Route one example'
  parent: example.route
  weight: 1

example.route.two:
  title: 'Route Two'
  route_name: example.route.two
  description: 'Route two example'
  parent: example.route
  weight: 2
```

Routing File - exmaple.routing.yml

```
example.route:
  path: '/admin/route'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
    _title: 'Route Example'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'

example.route.one:
  path: '/admin/route/one'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Route one'
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::contentOne'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::routeOne'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
    
example.route.two:
  path: '/admin/route/two'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Route two'
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::contentTwo'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::routeTwo'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```

Controller for custom access - ExampleController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Defines a route controller .
 */
class ExampleController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function routeOne() {
    if (TRUE) {
      $response = new RedirectResponse(Url::fromRoute('example.route.two')->setAbsolute()->toString());
      $response->send();
      return AccessResult::forbidden();
    }
    else {
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function routeTwo() {
    return AccessResult::allowed();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function contentOne() {
    return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->t("hello route one"),
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function contentTwo() {
    return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->t("hello route two"),
    ];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue if you click/visit `example.route` it automatically redirects to `example.route.two` is caused by the access method not only called when you visit `example.route.one`, but also on other pages with links pointing to `example.route.one`, for example in a menu.

So use access methods only for calculating access results. If this then results in a 403 you can catch it in an event subscriber and set a redirect response instead of the default 403 message.

See [Dynamically change the "access denied page" title and body](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299680/dynamically-change-the-access-denied-page-title-and-body).